# I can not filter songs based on selected decades in flutter dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have 2 dart files called main.dart and spotify_service.dart. The app is basically filtering according to user's preferences based on genre and year and gives some recommendation using a recommendation query of Spotify API while fetching data. I'am trying to give some recommendations to users. It shows some songs according to genre but the problem is decade filtering is not working. I am using Spotify API. If you could you help me,i would be glad?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'spotify_service.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Spotify Search',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final SpotifyService _spotifyService = SpotifyService(
    clientId: '',
    clientSecret: '',
  );

  List<Map<String, dynamic>> _recommendationResults = [];
  // Define a list of genres
  List<String> _genres = [
    'pop',
    'rock',
    'hip-hop',
    'jazz',
    // Add more genres as needed
  ];

  String _selectedGenre = 'pop'; // Default genre
  String _selectedDecade = '2020s'; // Default decade/year
  void _recommend() async {
    final genre = _selectedGenre; // Use the selected genre
    final decadeRange = _getYearRange(_selectedDecade);

    final results = await _spotifyService.recommendTracks(
      genre,
      decadeRange,
    );
    setState(() {
      _recommendationResults = results;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Spotify Recommendations'),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            DropdownButton<String>(
              value: _selectedGenre,
              onChanged: (String? newValue) {
                setState(() {
                  _selectedGenre = newValue!;
                });
              },
              items: _genres.map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
                return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                  value: value,
                  child: Text(value),
                );
              }).toList(),
            ),
            DropdownButton<String>(
              value: _selectedDecade,
              onChanged: (String? newValue) {
                setState(() {
                  _selectedDecade = newValue!;
                });
              },
              items: [
                '1960s',
                '1970s',
                '1980s',
                '1990s',
                '2000s',
                '2010s',
                '2020s'
              ].map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
                return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                  value: value,
                  child: Text(value),
                );
              }).toList(),
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: _recommend,
              child: Text('Recommend'),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 16),
            Expanded(
              child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: _recommendationResults.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return _buildRecommendationTile(index);
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildRecommendationTile(int index) {
    final String trackName = _recommendationResults[index]['name'] ?? '';
    final String artistName = _getArtistName(index);
    final String albumCoverUrl = _getAlbumCoverUrl(index);
    final String releaseDate =
        _recommendationResults[index]['album']['release_date'] ?? '';
    final String decade = _getDecade(releaseDate);

    return ListTile(
      title: Text(trackName),
      subtitle: Text(
          '$artistName  - $decade\nRelease Date: $releaseDate'), // Added release date
      leading: albumCoverUrl.isNotEmpty
          ? Image.network(albumCoverUrl,
          width: 50, height: 50, fit: BoxFit.cover)
          : Icon(Icons.music_note),
      trailing: IconButton(
        icon: Icon(Icons.favorite),
        onPressed: () {
          // Handle favorite button press
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  String _getArtistName(int index) {
    final List<dynamic> artists =
        _recommendationResults[index]['artists'] ?? [];
    return artists.isNotEmpty ? artists[0]['name'] ?? '' : '';
  }

  String _getAlbumCoverUrl(int index) {
    final Map<String, dynamic> album =
        _recommendationResults[index]['album'] ?? {};
    final List<dynamic> images = album['images'] ?? [];
    return images.isNotEmpty ? images[0]['url'] ?? '' : '';
  }

  String _getYearRange(String decade) {
    int startYear = int.parse(decade.substring(0, 4));
    int endYear = startYear + 9;
    return '$startYear-$endYear';
  }

}

String _getDecade(String releaseDate) {
  try {
    int year = int.parse(releaseDate.substring(0, 4)); // Cover the entire year

    if (year >= 1960 && year < 1970) {
      return '1960s';
    } else if (year >= 1970 && year < 1980) {
      return '1970s';
    } else if (year >= 1980 && year < 1990) {
      return '1980s';
    } else if (year >= 1990 && year < 2000) {
      return '1990s';
    } else if (year >= 2000 && year < 2010) {
      return '2000s';
    } else if (year >= 2010 && year < 2020) {
      return '2010s';
    } else if (year >= 2020) {
      return '2020s';
    } else {
      // Default to empty string or another appropriate value
      return '';
    }
  } catch (e) {
    // Handle parsing error, return a default value or an empty string
    return '';
  }
} import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class SpotifyService {
  final String clientId;
  final String clientSecret;
  final String base64Encoded;

  SpotifyService({required this.clientId, required this.clientSecret})
      : base64Encoded = base64.encode(utf8.encode('$clientId:$clientSecret'));

  Future<String> _getAccessToken() async {
    final response = await http.post(
      Uri.parse('https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token'),
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Basic $base64Encoded',
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      },
      body: {'grant_type': 'client_credentials'},
    );

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final jsonResponse = json.decode(response.body);
      final accessToken = jsonResponse['access_token'] as String;

      return accessToken;
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to get access token');
    }
  }

  Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> recommendTracks(
      String genre,
      String? releaseDateRange, // Updated parameter
      ) async {
    final accessToken = await _getAccessToken();

    // Construct the recommendation endpoint URL with additional parameters
    final recommendationUrl =
        'https://api.spotify.com/v1/recommendations?seed_genres=$genre';
    final List<String> filters = [];
    filters.add('release_date:$releaseDateRange');

    final String filtersString = filters.isNotEmpty ? '&${filters.join('&')}' : '';
    // Debug print statement
    print('Recommendation URL: $recommendationUrl$filtersString');

    final response = await http.get(
      Uri.parse('$recommendationUrl$filtersString'),
      headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer $accessToken'},
    );


    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final jsonResponse = json.decode(response.body);
      final tracks = jsonResponse['tracks'] as List<dynamic>;
      // Debug print statement
      print('Number of Tracks: ${tracks.length}');

      return tracks.map((track) {
        return {
          'name': track['name'] as String,
          'artists': track['artists'] as List<dynamic>,
          'album': {
            'images': track['album']['images'] as List<dynamic>,
            'release_date':
            track['album']['release_date'] as String, // Added release_date
          },
        };
      }).toList();
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to recommend tracks');
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no such a filter `release_date` on Spotify API `Request` section.

https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/get-recommendations

You can always achieve this to filter out the `Response` as `Array<TrackObject>` is returned and has `release_date` property on it.

Answer (score 0):

## You need a small changing in your code

```
// Modify _getYearRange to handle decade input 

String _getYearRange(String decade) {

  int startYear = int.parse(decade.substring(0, 4));

  int endYear = startYear + 9;

  return '$startYear-01-01T00:00:00Z,$endYear-12-31T23:59:59Z';

}

  Now, update the recommendTracks method in the SpotifyService class:

  Future>> recommendTracks( 

  String genre,

  String? releaseDateRange,

) async {

  // ... (existing code)

  final recommendationUrl = 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/recommendations?

seed_genres=$genre';

  final List filters = [];
  
  // Check if releaseDateRange is not null

  if (releaseDateRange != null) {

    filters.add('release_date:$releaseDateRange');

  }

  final String filtersString = filters.isNotEmpty ? '&${filters.join('&')}' : '';

  print('Recommendation URL: $recommendationUrl$filtersString');

  // ... (existing code)

}
```